# Recover Files in iCloud

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, garageband, file-recovery

I uploaded a garageband song-file to iCloud on my iPad. Unfortunately i deleted it from iCloud (on my iPad) and its gone on both my iCloud drive and iPad local storage. Is it possible to recover my deleted file on iCloud or iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're in luck — this is in fact possible!

[Login to iCloud](https://icloud.com), and then click your name in the top right of the page, and then click "iCloud Settings." Scroll to the bottom of the page, and in the bottom left hand corner you should see an "Advanced" box:

[image: The Advanced section.]

Then, click "Restore Files," and it will take you to this window:

[image: File recovery]

If your files are not in this window, then I'm afraid you're out of luck!

Comment: It shows "No files to restore". I think it is because i deleted it from my iPad and not a mac computer.

Comment: @HamMan4Ever I'm not sure if that makes a difference. It sounds like the file might be gone...